# Type hints for overriding covariant init parameters

Tags: python, python-typing

I'd like to have a concrete class override the type for an instance variable in a Protocol with a default implementation. In the example below, the `Parent` class has a `ref` attribute that is of type `BaseRef`. The `Child` subclass takes a covariant reference of type `SubRef`.

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Protocol
T_co = TypeVar('T_co', bound='BaseRef', covariant=True)

class BaseRef:
    pass

class SubRef(BaseRef):
    pass

class Parent(Protocol[T_co]):
    ref: T_co
    
    def __init__(self, ref: T_co) -> None:
        self.ref = ref

class Child(Parent[SubRef]):
    def __init__(self, ref: SubRef) -> None:
        super().__init__(ref)

child = Child()
```

The best option I could come up with is using a generic in the `Parent` definition as shown in the example above. This works correctly for references inside the body of `Child`. However, without the matching `ref: SubRef` in the init parameter specification, the required type doesn't show up when initializing. In other words:

```py
c = Child()  # type hint shows up as "(ref: T_co@Parent)" instead of "(ref: SubRef)"
```

Is there a way to override type hints in the `Child` definition that works in both the class body and in instance initialization that doesn't require annotating `SubRef` twice?

Comment: Making the child less generic than the parent is (probably) a violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: @chepner the Parent type isn't intended to be used directly. Updated the question so that it is a protocol with a default.

Comment: You don't have to instantiate `Parent` directly to have problems. Consider a statically typed list `x : list[Parent[T]]`. Some of those might be `Child` instances, others might be `Child2` instances.

Comment: You initial question was clearer. The protocol usage here is just unnecessarily confusing. _"the required type doesn't show up when initializing."_ If you mean your IDE does not give you the correct auto-suggestion for the type of the `ref` argument in `Child` that is an issue with your IDE's type checker. Because simply inheriting from the generic alias type `Parent[SubRef]` is sufficient to bind `T_co` for the entire class, meaning it will be specified to `SubRef` and all other references to that type variable will collapse to that.

Comment: @chepner I am afraid you are mistaken. `Child` is a subtype of `Parent[T]`, specifically of `Parent[SubRef]`. Annotating `x: list[Parent[T]]` will only cause problems, if you attempted to make `x` contain `Parent[T1]` **and** `Parent[T2]` where `T1` is not `T2`. And that covers the `Child` case as well. If we had `Child2` inheriting from `Parent[FooBar]`, then `x` cannot contain both `Child` and `Child2` instances. That is all. Nothing about this violates the LSP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your *initial* code sample:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


T_co = TypeVar('T_co', bound='BaseRef', covariant=True)


class BaseRef:
    pass


class SubRef(BaseRef):
    pass


class Parent(Generic[T_co]):
    def __init__(self, ref: T_co) -> None:
        self.ref: T_co = ref


class Child(Parent[SubRef]):
    pass
```

This is all you need and it is perfectly valid. You can see that the constructor signature for `Child` is correctly inferred by a competent type checker by adding `reveal_type(Child)` and running that code through `mypy`. The output will be:

```
note: Revealed type is "def (ref: SubRef) -> Child"
```

What is happening here is that `Parent[SubRef]` returns a [generic alias type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#generic-alias-type), where `T_co` is fixed to `SubRef` and when `Child` inherits from that, all annotations with `T_co` collapse to `SubRef`.

That includes the `ref` annotation in the `__init__` method. If we were to try and pass something else, e.g. some other subclass of `BaseRef`, we would get an error by the type checker.

```py
...

class OtherRef(BaseRef):
    pass


Child(OtherRef())  # error
```

Again, the `mypy` output:

```
error: Argument 1 to "Child" has incompatible type "OtherRef"; expected "SubRef"  [arg-type]
```

If you are not happy with the **auto-suggestion** you get from your IDE, you should probably bring that to the attention of the devs behind that IDE or more specifically the type checker used by it.

But at least with PyCharm, even though I get the suggestion `ref: T_co`, when I start typing `Child(`, which is not ideal (it is *definitely* supposed to be `SubRef`), at least it also complains loudly, when I try the `Child(OtherRef())`, telling me `Expected type 'SubRef' (matched generic type 'T_co'), got 'OtherRef' instead`.

Comment: Thanks @Daniil Fajnberg for the comprehensive write up. Given that the revealed type matches expectations, prob just not happy with how IDE chooses to display the hint. Wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.